# WebContent folder in Eclipse Project Explorer is not in sync with the deployed application

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web-applications

The path to the WebContent directory of my dynamic web application in Eclipse is (**Directory A**)

```
C:\PathToWORKSPACE\Project\WebContent
```

However, when I deploy the project in Tomcat within Eclipse, the project is deployed at (**Directory B**)

```
C:\PathToWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Project
```

---

I am writing a file within the web application and saving it at the servlet context's path, which is the same as the deployed directory (**Directory B**) within Eclipse (C:\PathToWorkspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Project) I do find that the file is created appropriately; however, the file does not appear within the WebContent directory (**Directory A**) of my dynamic web application.

Does this happen since these two directories are not synchronized. How can I resolve this inconsistency?

Answer (score 0):

You could configure tomcat on eclipse so that eclipse allows to use external directory for tomcat to be used.[image]
If you cannot update the server locations, you could delele the tomcat and add the tomcat again, then you could be able to update it.